# AWS getting generic clients

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I've been building a Lambda function in AWS that makes use of the following items, S3, SQS, SNS and KMS. While switching between unit tests and actual lambda tests I have written a generic method to return the IAmazonService interface, that interface is like the below

```
public static T GetAmazonClient<T>(ILambdaContext context) where T : IAmazonService, new()
{
    T client = default(T);
    try
    {    
        if (context.GetType() == typeof(TestLambdaContext))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a unit test and I will have to build a profile");
            //Build the profile for my unit test
            client = ClientObjectIhaveBuilt;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a Lambda instance and I should inherit my credentials");
            client = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Some logging happens here with the exception
    }
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client));
    return client;
}
```

Then in my code I can do something like this

```
using (var sqsClient = AmazonClientHelper.GetAmazonClient<AmazonSQSClient>(context))
{
    var request = new ChangeMessageVisibilityRequest(SQSURL, message.ReceiptHandle, timeout);
    Console.WriteLine("Extending Visibility of SQS Entry");
    var response = await sqsClient.ChangeMessageVisibilityAsync(request);
}
```

In Unit Testing this has worked absolutely fine, I am able to retrieve messages, read from S3 and everything else I wish to do, but when hosted in AWS the Lambda doesn't seem to be creating the right client accounts.

I have hosted this in my own testing AWS account and had it work end to end fine, but when uploading it to my company account I find that the client objects created do not instantiate correctly, the client object output in the JSON serialiser at the end is blank object with no service URL or credentials (this may be correct but looks suspect)

Our clients break down at the first hurdle when we try to extend visibility on our SQS items; The client tries to extend visibility but we encounter an operation cancelled request.

NB: Sit tight, I'm trying to get a copy of the stacktrace and serialised client output

Comment: Different version of the .net runtime in the Lambda environment? Lack of credentials in the Lambda environment? I'm assuming that your catch handler would actually log any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a red herring; there was nothing wrong with the code above.

The issue was with SQS, AWS requires that we use the URL of the SQS, this means that the VPC for our Lambda needed to have access to either the internet, or at least AWS Endpoints via certain NAT/Subnet rules.